# Active admin dependant filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I've the following active admin filter:

```
f.input :country, as: :select, :collection => [['USA','usa'],['India','india'],['China','china']], :prompt => "Select country", required: true
```

And the values for this filter are static. I've another hash of states with keys as these countries.

```
states = {
 'usa'=> ['texas','florida','georgia'],
 'india'=> ['goa','karnataka','gujarat'],
 'china'=>['yunnan','hunan','henan']
}
```

Now I have another filter to select states. When I select `india` from the first dropdown, the second filter must be populated with the states from india.